# Nightmarejs How to read values from a file and insert values into a web page

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, nightmare

So, I need to open a website, insert a value from a txt file and then submit it. Over and over again until the end of the txt file.

```js
//TXT file example
value1
value2
value3
...
value1000
```

Something like this:

```js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('/example/path/file.txt')
});

nightmare
  .goto('https://example.html')

  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {//Reading line
   .type('#TXT_BOX', line)
   .click('#BTN_SUBMIT')
   .end()
   .then(function (result) {
     console.log('Inserted value: ', line)
   })
   .refresh()//Refresh the page to insert new value
  });

  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

I already managed to make the code work with only one value at a time, and I call the nightmare script from a bash that reads the values, but this is so slow because it opens electron every time, it's running on ubuntu and I'm using "xvfb-run" to make it work, and every time I insert a value open the xvfb process and electron. So, I believe that if I read the data from inside the js script it would be a lot faster.